# How to count replicates in an array

Tags: matlab, matrix

If you have the following array

```
a = [1 1 3 4 4 1 1 4 4 4];
```

I want to get this result

```
b = [1 3 4 1 4];
c = [2 1 2 2 3];
```

b is an array with unique adjacent values from a,

c is an array that counts the number of repetition

**Is there a way to do this without loops?**

Comment: What you are asking for is [run length encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding).  This has been asked to death here on StackOverflow.  The one I linked to is one of the more popular posts.  If you look at Mohsen's answer, simply equate `numCode` with your input array.

Comment: Yes, Mohsen's code works as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach with [`diff`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) -

```
b = a([true diff(a)~=0])
c = diff(find([1 diff(a)~=0 1]))
```